# sql server query - get database tables schema and relations

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

Is there a possibility to get the full database schema including table columns, indexex, views, relations, etc, with sql queries?

- get a list of all views from the database
- get a list of all users from the database
- get a list of all stored procedures from the database
- get a list of all functions from the database
- get a list of all tables from database and foreach table get:

  - get a list of all indexes
  - get a list of all keys (PK, FK)
  - get a list of all constraints
  - get a list of all indexes
  - get a list of all columns and foreach column get:

    - Name
    - PK / FK
    - Type (nvarchar, int, ..etc)
    - Not Null

Comment: Yes it is possible, using `sys.` schema views. The question is how do you want to use it. If you want creation script use `Generate Script` from SSMS or Redgate tool for moving db to version control. If you want build ERD use tool that can do reverse enginering based on connection to DB.

Comment: What about INFORMATION_SCHEMA.... views? What's the difference or benefits between sys schema and information schema?

Comment: INFORMATION_SCHEMA generaly contains less info, check documentation. Anyway I would recommend to use specific tool instead of hand crafting own solution.

Comment: INFORMATION_SCHEMA is part of the ANSI standard, which is one potential upside. As @lad2025 says though, it doesn't include as much information.

Comment: @lad2025: I am trying now SSMS but I cannot access the sys. schema views, I believe the system views are hidden from designer?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM sys.columns`? Maybe you have not sufficient priviliges.

Comment: I mean I can run queries against sys.columns and get the data and so on but if I use the query designer, I cannot see any views in the views tab, but I can see all tables ...

Comment: Do you need to see the list of DB objects or to obtain scripts creating them?

Comment: @IvanStarostin: to see the list of DB objects

Comment: Why object inspector is not enough?

Answer (score 1):

As @lad2025 comments - yes, this is possible by querying the sys. schema. [Technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189082%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [tutorial](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/exploring-your-database-schema-with-sql/) available.